# How does SSL-VPN tunneling and encryption work?

Tags: vpn, ssl, tcp, tls

I have a few questions on SSL-VPN (Tunnel, not portal version). Question 1 is probably the one I'd like answered the most, out of my four questions.

1. How exactly does SSL-VPN tunneling work (Feel free to just point me to a link – Google seemed to only return references to the portal version)?
   Does the SSL-VPN tunnel connection work by authenticating between two servers, using digital certificates and then simply encrypts the packets using SSL, at the internet layer and then decrypts them at the other end of the tunnel?
2. SSL-VPN is a VPN encrypted with SSL, so does this mean it works at the internet layer, as opposed to SSL which is transport layer and IPSec which is network layer?
3. Is there no TLS-VPN?
4. For a SSL-VPN tunnel I thought you need client software like Cisco AnyConnect, yet I have read online that you dont need any additional software – is this probably because they're referring to the non-tunnel (portal) SSL-VPN?

Comment: I can only answer #3 - there's practically no difference; both SSLv3 and TLSv1 are very similar, so when people say "SSL" they usually mean "SSL/TLS" or "any version of SSL or TLS".

Comment: Take a look at this article http://www.alliancedatacom.com/how-vpn-works.asp